# How to access to class property?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code:

```
function myClass() {

    this.tabs = new Array();

    myClass.prototype.focus_tab = function animateTab(nr){
        for(i=0;i<this.tabs.length;i++){
            $('#' + i + '-image').stop().animate(
                { left: '100px' },
                100 , function(){
                    this.tabs[i].step = 1;
                }
            );
        }
}
```

but function at the end of the animation does not recognize "this.tabs". 
How to do it well?

Comment: There are no classes in Javascript.

Comment: Id's starting with a digit is not valid html.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's in a a different scope, try:

```
function myClass() {
  this.tabs = new Array();

  myClass.prototype.focus_tab = function animateTab(nr){
     for(i=0;i<this.tabs.length;i++){
         var mytab = this.tabs[i];
         $('#' + i + '-image').stop().animate({ left: '100px' }, 100 , function(){
             mytab.step = 1;
         }
      );
  }
}
```

There are some other issues as well, but the comments on the question already adress some of them!

Answer (score 0):

This is another example of the [classic scoping issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1451009/javascript-infamous-loop-problem).  You only have one `i` variable, shared for all your callbacks. You need to make a local `i` for each callback.  Changing you callback from:

```
function(){
    this.tabs[i].step = 1;
}
```

To:

```
(function(i){
    return function(){
        this.tabs[i].step = 1;
    }
})(i)
```